# Problem with method equation to checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net

One of my projects is having an error involving checkboxes and a method.
[image]

Whenever any item under Misc is checked, a 6% tax rate is applied to the total pricing of the selected item(s). However, when I have an item checked under both **Oil and Lube** it doesn't apply the tax at all and puts it at $0.00 under summary. If I have just a **Flush** item checked and not **Oil and Lube**, it works, but I still can't have both of these checked at the same time with a **Misc** item. The **Misc** items are considered **Parts**. **Oil and Lube** as well as **Flushes** are considered **Services**.

```
    private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                // Sets variables to 0
                double oil = 0;
                double lube = 0;
                double radiator = 0;
                double trans = 0;
                double inspection = 0;
                double muffler = 0;
                double tire = 0;

                if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    oil = 26;
                }
                if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    lube = 18;
                }
                if (radiatorCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    radiator = 30;
                }
                if (transmissionCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    trans = 80;
                }
                if (inspectionCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    inspection = 15;
                }
                if (replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    muffler = 100;
                }
                if (tireRotationCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    tire = 20;
                }

                // Values and methods called as variables
                double parts = double.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);
                double labor = double.Parse(laborTextBox.Text);
                double oillube = OilLubeCharges(oil, lube);
                double flush = FlushCharges(radiator, trans);
                double misc = MiscCharges(inspection, muffler, tire);
                double other = OtherCharges(parts, labor);
                double tax = TaxCharges(parts, labor, oillube, flush, misc);
                double total = TotalCharges(oillube, flush, misc, other, tax, parts);
                double services = oillube + flush + misc;

                // Summary box of labels
                totalServiceAndLaborLabel.Text = services.ToString("c");
                totalPartsLabel.Text = other.ToString();
                totalTaxLabel.Text = tax.ToString("c");
                totalFeesLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");

            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Displays an error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private double OilLubeCharges(double oil, double lube)
    {
        return oil + lube;
        // Returns charges of oil and lube
    }

    private double FlushCharges(double radiator, double trans)
    {
        // Returns total of radiator flush and transmission
        return radiator + trans;
    }
    private double MiscCharges(double inspection, double muffler, double tire)
    {
        // Returns total of inspection, muffler and tire rotation
        return inspection + muffler + tire;
    }
    private double OtherCharges(double parts, double labor)
    {
        // Returns total for other services
        return parts + labor - labor;
    }

    private double TaxCharges(double parts, double labor, double oillube, double flush, double misc)
    {
        if (parts != 0 && labor != 0 && (flush != 0 &&  oillube != 0))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
            // Returns tax on parts
            return (0.06 * misc);
    }

    private double TotalCharges(double oillube, double flush, double misc, double other, double tax, double parts)
    {
        // Returns total charges
        return oillube + flush + misc + other + tax - parts;
    }

    private void ClearOilLube()
    {
        if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            oilChangeCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
        if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            lubeJobCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
    }
    private void ClearFlushes()
    {
        if (radiatorCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            radiatorCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
        if (transmissionCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            transmissionCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
    }
    private void ClearMisc()
    {
        if (inspectionCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            inspectionCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
        if (replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
        if (tireRotationCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            tireRotationCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
    }
    private void ClearOther()
    {
        // Clear textboxes
        partsTextBox.Text = null;
        laborTextBox.Text = null;
    }
    private void ClearFees()
    {
        // Clear labels
        totalServiceAndLaborLabel.Text = null;
        totalPartsLabel.Text = null;
        totalTaxLabel.Text = null;
        totalFeesLabel.Text = null;
    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // Clear all checkboxes and textboxes within called methods below
            ClearOilLube();
            ClearFlushes();
            ClearMisc();
            ClearOther();
            ClearFees();
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Closes the form
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

The assignment question states that "TaxCharges—Returns the amount of sales tax, if any. Sales tax is 6% and is charged only on parts. If the customer purchases services only, no sales tax is charged."

[image]

This is the code that concerns the tax application.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this not work? Why the additional complexity:

```
    private double TaxCharges(double parts, double misc)
    {
        if (parts == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            // Returns tax on parts
            return (0.06 * misc);
    }
```